# Quaternion space is irreducible in $M_{4n}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that $i$ is in the complex space $\mathbb{C}$ that since $\mathbb{C}$ sits in $M_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ properly, apply the isomorphism $\chi :\mathbb{C} \to M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$. Hence, \begin{eqnarray*}
i\to
\chi(i)=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\in M_{2}(\mathbb{R}).
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, the characteristic polynomial of $\chi(i)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[X]$, it follows that $\chi(i)$ is irreducible in $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$. Hence, $\mathbb{C}$ is irreducible in $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$.
Now, Quaternion space $\mathbb{H}$ sits in $M_{4}(\mathbb{R})$, properly. 
$\mathbb{H}$ is irreducible in $M_{4}(\mathbb{R})$. Why? In this case, we can not use characteristic polynomial because for every element $x$ in $\mathbb{H}$, characteristic polynomial of $\chi(x)$ has degree 4 that is not irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[X]$ ($\chi:\mathbb{H}\to M_{4}(\mathbb{R})$).

Comment: Irreducible as a variety? Transitive in what sense? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Irreducibility: If there is a nontrivial invariant subspace in $\mathbb{R}^{4\times 1}$ (1) and in $\mathbb{C}^{2\times 1}$ (2) under $\mathbb{H}$.